# Overloaded method with template

Tags: c++

I've got the following classes:

```
class A: public Util<double> {}

class B: public Util<double>, public Interface {}

template<class T>
class MyTmp {
public:
    void foo(const A& a);
}


class MyClass: public MyTmp<Other> {
public:
   void foo(const B& b);
}
```

When I call `foo` using an instance of `MyClass` with a `A` object for unknown reason the `foo` method of `MyClass` is called instead of `foo` of class `MyTmp`. I'm using gcc 4.4.2 using -O3. Any tips?

Comment: What do you mean it calls the `foo` method of `MyClass`? You mean... the code doesn't compile? An `A` is not a `B`.

Comment: @Barry No the code compiles but at runtime the wrong method is called. It's really strange. However after the application of TartanLlama's solution, now the program works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Member functions in derived classes with the same names as those in base classes *hide* the functions in the base class.

If you want `MyTmp<T>::foo` to be available from `MyClass`, you could as a using-directive:

```
class MyClass: public MyTmp<Other> {
public:
   using MyTmp::foo;
   void foo(const B& b);
}
```